# Using segment on React and calling "analytics.default.track" errors "Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: reactjs, analytics, mixpanel, segment

I am using react-segment and on my .js file I have

```
//1. the following is initialised once
let analytics = require('react-segment');

//2. the following is called each time the user does something
analytics.default.load("CODE");
analytics.default.track('EVENT', {});
```

The first time (2.) is called both the page and track event are sent to segment. The second time only the load call (page event) goes through and I am getting the error

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Note: this happens even when I disable the mixpanel integration

Comment: This may be coming due to infinite loop. Please check if you setting state or something that might be calling render function

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you call `setState` method inside component `render()` or even worse you modified state directly. So every render will cause state modification which will cause render and so on. Move state modification logic to `componentDidUpdate` or `componentDidMount`